# C - Pointer Subtraction

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I've thought I understood pointers and pointers arithmetic but then I came across something unexpected to me. When I run this code I thought I was going to see "(header+1) - header = 32" as output. But I didnt. Can someone explain me why this was happened ?

```
    struct metadata *header = (struct metadata *)malloc(sizeof(struct metadata));
    printf("Struct size of : %d\n",sizeof(struct metadata));
    printf("header = %d header+1 = %d\n",header,header+1);
    printf("(header+1) - header = %d\n",(header+1) - header);
```

This gives the following output :

Struct size of : 32

header = 37704768 header+1 = 37704800

(header+1) - header = 1

Comment: X - X is 0 ... in general, isn't it. Also dare to explain why "*I thought I was going to see "(header+1) - header = 32"*"?

Comment: The reason you get `1` is related to why you can't add two pointers in C.

Comment: @alk For example int *x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10) will create an int array with 10 members. so whenever you want to access the fifth element you can use x[5] or *(x + 5)  which are identical (or also &x[5] and (x + 5)) . So that x + 5 means actually adding sizeof(int)*5 to the beginning address of the array. So the sizeof(struct metadata) is 32 so you do the math :) And also If I casted int * to char * - such as ((char *)x + 5) it would only add 5 since sizeof(char) is always 1 byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **[standard 6.5.6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6)**

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;
>   **the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements**.

Here if you consider it an one element array, then two pointers - one of them are pointing to that element and 1 past the element. So that results in 1. The above rule obviously tells us that the result is scaled up by the sizeof the type that the pointers points to.

Also from same [**standard 6.5.6**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9) where it is specified that 1 past the array element a pointer can point

> Moreover, **if the expression `P` points either to an element of an
>   array object or one past the last element of an array object, and the
>   expression `Q` points to the last element of the same array object,
>   the expression `((Q)+1)-(P)` has the same value as ((Q)-(P))+1**and as
>   -((P)-((Q)+1)), and has the value zero if the expression P points one past > the last element of the array object, even though the
>   expression (Q)+1 does not point to an element of the array object

#### If I cast them into void *, I will get 32 right ?

Yes.  it will be `32`(if you are using `gcc`). `sizeof(void)=1` (gcc makes it like that - not specified standard) but most probably other compiler will generate error which can be resolved by using `char*`.As `sizeof char` is `1` you can use `char*` casting to get the same result.  As per standard this is not specified and illegal since `void` is an incomplete type.

Better to use `char*` casting to get the difference in bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: If I cast them into void *, I will get 32 right ? Because there is no type defined in void as variable so they can't be the element of an array right ?

Comment: @Khan9797 If you cast them to `char *`, you should get 32.  Trying to subtract `void *` pointers is problematic, as arithmetic on `void *` pointers is undefined.  (Pointer arithmetic always involves scaling by the size of the pointed-to object, and sizeof(void) is either undefined, or 0.)

Comment: @Khan9797.: Edited my answer check once.